# Best way to learn every way I am tracked online?

Tags: web-browser, spoofing, user-tracking

Is there a course or resource for a person with basic networking skills to see all ways a website like FB or Google can track and identify users + how to spoof them and look natural? Not for malicious activity just feel frustrated by the lack of information available on this online. Like, let's say I have 2 devices on 2 wifi networks. A website like FB would be able to separate them as 2 legit individuals through browser fingerprinting / IP detection / Cookies etc. I want to learn how to emulate this on one device on one wifi network while remaining as natural as the 2 user case.

Comment: This is a little like asking for all the ways one can get sick and then all the ways to fake each illness. Can you narrow the question a little?

Comment: While not an answer per se, a useful tool to get started with understanding is **Ghostery** .  https://www.ghostery.com/ . There are other tools I consider better, but Ghostery has the advantage of being easy to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Some resources for you to play with, focussed mostly at the application layer:

- https://browserleaks.com
- https://amiunique.com
- https://panopticlick.eff.org/
- https://prism-break.org/en/
- https://www.privacytools.io/
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy

Instal the *uMatrix* add-on in your browser, to get a feel for how it all works on your favourite websites, but also [be aware that development has now ended](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/09/20/umatrix-development-has-ended/). Study tracking techniques that are tested by the resources I linked to above; *Doles 2020* https://performancein.com/news/2020/09/15/first-party-vs-third-party-tracking-cookies-what-they-are-and-why-you-should-drop-them/ gives a good overview of the various techniques.

Read up on VPNs, and consider using a **paid-for** service .. *repeat after me: "There's no such thing as a free VPN!"* https://thatoneprivacysite.net/ .. but while you're at it, be aware of the limitations: from [*Proceedings of privacy enhancing technologies*](https://petsymposium.org/), *Pulls and Dahlberg 2020* https://petsymposium.org/2020/files/papers/issue1/popets-2020-0013.pdf

> Website Fingerprinting (WF) attacks are a
> subset of traffic analysis attacks where a local passive attacker attempts to infer which websites a target victim is visiting over an encrypted tunnel ...

If you're on your android phone, consider installing a software firewall, eg: [*NetGuard*](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/FAQ.md), which runs as a VPN to capture traffic. (This will be incompatible if you're using another VPN on your phone, as VPN can't be 'chained' that I know of.)

Another option is to check out [*AF-Wall*](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/FAQ) which works on `iptables` (for the most part I think this one requires root on your phone to get access to the `iptables` binary, but may not in some cases).

I'll assume you're considering isolating your browser inside a VM, based on your other question today. Make sure your host is only exposing a generic L2-network interface to the guest(s).

Better yet, if you're using wifi, and you leak your nearby SSIDs 'somehow', then you can be placed in a populated area to within 25 yards or even less - how can you trust that your browser isn't relaying this information? Your kernel? Consider switching to wired ethernet for your connectivity - for the most part, it's easier than you think. Disable wifi in the hardware - yep, rip that f***er out and don't look back! *Lounging on the couch doing 'research' only leads to crippling rsi in the long run, anyway!*