# How can I best obfuscate surveillance against my browser?

Tags: web-browser, defense, surveillance

I mostly use the Tails browser, but I also use Firefox in Fedora with several add-ons such as TrackMeNot, HTTPS Everywhere, uBlock Origin, NoScript, and Fingerprint Detector.

I would like to obfuscate collection against myself when I use Firefox. I do not consider active attack, only passive.

CC Cleaner and AVG Internet Security are used to remove cookies.

What more can I do?  I am not only talking about fingerprinting, which has been answered elsewhere.  **I want to obfuscate all possible data against collection of every sort**, and surely someone on this venerable website can address my question.

Comment: First of all, removing all cookies regularly in and of itself is a noticable thing. Secondly, what exactly is your threat model? Ad agencies? Facebook? The NSA? Third Echelon?

Comment: you can combine uBlock and NoScript into *[uMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix)*, which is now (sadly) inactive - at its last iteration it was highly functional, and (most of) the lists it works off continue to be updated (a team may yet pick up the ongoing maintenance of this add-on)

Comment: @MechMK1  I am not sure how to put it.  I want to hinder commercial collection.

Comment: @Patriot Then using those addons already solves this pretty much. More paranoia won't yield better results.

Comment: you can use a vpn, especially if you use wifi on older/ abandoned/ public-facing access points (you don't necessarily need your exit-point to the open internet to be in a anonymity-preserving jurisdiction if that's not part of your threat model) - you should absolutely be running a firewall on your *Fedora* host

Comment: @brynk Why do you assume routing all your traffic through one private company is somehow an improvement?

Comment: you need to get comfortable with `about:config` because, by default, the nature of *Firefox* is to chat about your internet activity with 3rd parties: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=firefox+modify+about%3Aconfig+privacy&ia=web

Comment: @MechMK1 which one private company? your isp? or your vpn provider? or the hosting service that you run your own vpn on? (vpn mitigates failures in the lower layers, in your local environment - note i didn't specify which technology, nor how it's deployed)

Comment: @brynk If you set up a VPN service at a hosting provider, you also have to trust that hosting provider and the hosting provider's ISP. It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: Well as @MechMK1 points out, introducing a VPN introduces other parties, so it may not suit your requirements. It does, however, suit mine, with particular respect to the connectivity hardware (*whoarewe?*) that I'm not quite forced to rely on. More on configuring (and then checking) your browser: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/240802/

Comment: I used to use a noise generator something like https://noiszy.com/

Comment: @mentallurg  That definitely got part of it.  Thank you!

Comment: @brynk  If you could tell me more about using about:config in Firefox, that would be excellent.  I have used it, but I am not exactly sure what would be the most beneficial things to do.

Comment: big topic, but here's a good start (also see the links at the top of this doco): "Firefox about:config privacy settings" *0xDE57 '17-21* https://gist.github.com/0XDE57/fbd302cef7693e62c769

Comment: @brynk  Thank you very much!  I did not know that there had already been a good answer to my question.  I am very happy to have finally gotten this fixed.  Let me tell you, the Firefox add-on "Canvas Fingerprint Defender" and the others from the same people, all work like magic.

Comment: you're welcome - caution: you're now playing 'whack-a-mole' with the firefox settings every time the browser updates itself;  also, be aware that by default, firefox will disable all of your extensions in the event that it can't validate them - be sure to come up with some way of doing a test each time you must rely on the functionality (*note to self: ref to discussion about mozilla failing to replace the firefox extensions signing cert before the expiry date*)